# re-do for loop again

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array that has the following values

```
1,2,3
1,0,2
0,1,2
```

and an array that has the following values

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

What I want to achieve is first it starts from array[0]

```
 matrix[0][0] * array[0] = result1
 matrix[0][1] * array[1] = result2
 matrix[0][2] * array[2] = result3
 matrix[1][0] * array[0] = result4
 matrix[1][1] * array[1] = result5
 matrix[1][2] * array[2] = result6
 matrix[2][0] * array[0] = result7
 matrix[2][1] * array[1] = result8
 matrix[2][2] * array[2] = result9
```

After that it will go back redo the loop and but this time starting from array[3]

```
 matrix[0][0] * array[3] = result10
 matrix[0][1] * array[4] = result11
 matrix[0][2] * array[5] = result12
 matrix[1][0] * array[3] = result13
 matrix[1][1] * array[4] = result14
 matrix[1][2] * array[5] = result15
 matrix[2][0] * array[3] = result16
 matrix[2][1] * array[4] = result17
 matrix[2][2] * array[5] = result18
```

After that it will go back redo the loop and but this time starting from array[6]

```
 matrix[0][0] * array[6] = result19
 matrix[0][1] * array[7] = result20
 matrix[0][2] * array[8] = result21
 matrix[1][0] * array[6] = result22
 matrix[1][1] * array[7] = result23
 matrix[1][2] * array[8] = result24
 matrix[2][0] * array[6] = result25
 matrix[2][1] * array[7] = result26
 matrix[2][2] * array[8] = result27
```

I tried it out but cannot achieve my desired output. Please help.

---

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        int matrix[][] = new int[][] {
                                    {1,2,3},
                                    {1,0,2},
                                    {0,1,2}
                                 };
        int array[] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };

        int count = 0;
        int a = 0;
        int row = 0, col = 0;
        boolean done = false;
        while(!done) {
            for (row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
                for (col = 0; col < matrix.length; col++) {
                    a = matrix[row][col] * array[count];
                    if(col > 0) {
                        count++;
                    }
                    if(count > col && row != col) {
                            count = 0;
                    }
                    if(row == matrix.length-1 && col == matrix.length-1) {
                        count = count + 1;  
                    }   
                        System.out.println(count);
                }   
            }
            if(row == matrix.length-1 && col == matrix.length-1) {
                count = count + 1;  
            }   
            if(count == array.length) {
                done = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could rewrite your `"what I want to achieve"` section to use the indices, it would make it much more clear.

Comment: What problem, specifically, are you having with the attempt you made? Are you receiving error messages? Is it behaving unexpectedly (and if so, in what way)?

Comment: Is this a matrix multiplication operation? Is there another way we can understand your problem more easily?

Comment: well I tried rewriting it. hope it's clear now

Comment: Easy, I am writing the code for u. hold a couple of minutes

Comment: You don't appear to be outputting your answer (int a) anywhere. What output do you expect?

Comment: @FelixMarcus I output a. it will print out endless values of 0,1 and 2. that's why I removed

Comment: my answer using the loop is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code you could use: It outputs the result of each multiplication with the corresponding result index.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int matrix[][] = new int[][] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 0, 2 }, { 0, 1, 2 } };
    int array[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    int globalCount = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int row = 0, col = 0;
    boolean done = false;

    for (count = 0; count < array.length; count += 3) {
        for (row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                a = matrix[row][col] * array[count++];
                System.out.println("Result" + globalCount++ + " " + a);

            }
            count -= 3;

        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Result0 0
Result1 2
Result2 6
Result3 0
Result4 0
Result5 4
Result6 0
Result7 1
Result8 4
Result9 3
Result10 8
Result11 15
Result12 3
Result13 0
Result14 10
Result15 0
Result16 4
Result17 10
Result18 6
Result19 14
Result20 24
Result21 6
Result22 0
Result23 16
Result24 0
Result25 7
Result26 16
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you could do it with a simple `for` loop by incrementing the `array` index by 3 in each iteration. Something like,

```
int[][] matrix = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 0, 2 }, { 0, 1, 2 } };
int[][] result = new int[matrix.length][];
int[] array = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int t = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 3) {
    result[t++] = new int[] { matrix[0][0] * array[i],
            matrix[0][1] * array[i + 1], matrix[0][2] * array[i + 2],
            matrix[1][0] * array[i], matrix[1][1] * array[i + 1],
            matrix[1][2] * array[i + 2], matrix[2][0] * array[i],
            matrix[2][1] * array[i + 1], matrix[2][2] * array[i + 2] };
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void multiply(int[][] matrix, int[] array) {
        int sum = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int limit = 2;
        int end = 0;
        do {
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                    temp = matrix[i][j] * array[k];
                    sum += temp;
                    System.out.println("matrix[" + i + "][" + j + "] * array["
                            + k + "] = " + sum);
                    if (k < limit) {
                        k++;
                    } else {
                        k = end;
                    }
                    temp = 0;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            limit += 3;
            end += 3;
            k = end;
        } while (end < 9);
    }
```

output:

```
matrix[0][0] * array[0] = 0
matrix[0][1] * array[1] = 2
matrix[0][2] * array[2] = 8
matrix[1][0] * array[0] = 8
matrix[1][1] * array[1] = 8
matrix[1][2] * array[2] = 12
matrix[2][0] * array[0] = 12
matrix[2][1] * array[1] = 13
matrix[2][2] * array[2] = 17

matrix[0][0] * array[3] = 20
matrix[0][1] * array[4] = 28
matrix[0][2] * array[5] = 43
matrix[1][0] * array[3] = 46
matrix[1][1] * array[4] = 46
matrix[1][2] * array[5] = 56
matrix[2][0] * array[3] = 56
matrix[2][1] * array[4] = 60
matrix[2][2] * array[5] = 70

matrix[0][0] * array[6] = 76
matrix[0][1] * array[7] = 90
matrix[0][2] * array[8] = 114
matrix[1][0] * array[6] = 120
matrix[1][1] * array[7] = 120
matrix[1][2] * array[8] = 136
matrix[2][0] * array[6] = 136
matrix[2][1] * array[7] = 143
matrix[2][2] * array[8] = 159
```